# Difficult integral $\int u\, \partial_x \left[(\partial_x u)^2 + (\partial_y u)^2\right]\, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I need to integrate 
$\int u\, \partial_x \left[(\partial_x u)^2 + (\partial_y u)^2\right]\, \mathrm{d}x$.

In other words we need $w$ such that $\partial_x w = u\, \partial_x \left[(\partial_x u)^2 + (\partial_y u)^2\right]$. The only thing I know is that $\partial_{x}^2 u + \partial_y^2 u = \Delta u = 0$.

I have tried searching for $w$ but I never make progress. Any hints? The original form of the integral is
$\int u\, \partial_x \left(\partial_x^2 u^2 + \partial_y^2 u^2\right)\, \mathrm{d}x $, and I reduced it to the form given above (with the known antiderivatives left out), so solving either is fine and automatically solves the other.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just a wild guess: $u$ is harmonic. Can we exploit that?

Comment: I only wish! Although, I already have exploited that in producing the alternative integral from the original one.

Comment: Clarifications: $u$ is a function of $x$, and $y$; a simple integration by parts can be done to give $\int \left[ (\partial_x u)^3 +  (\partial_x u) (\partial_y u)^2 \right]\,\mathrm{d}x$, which does not look easy. $w$ should exist, but finding it is another matter.

Comment: The non-linearity + non-symmetric integrand (in the coordinates $x,y$) = very unlikely a simple formula for $w$ exists.